# NSOperation pass back data

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have been searching but can only find the delegate pattern idea to pass back data from a NSOperation.  I have a NSOperation that downloads data upon completion of that NSOperation I would like it to pass back to the class that put it in a NSoperationQueue the data it downloaded.  There could be upmost of 100 of these NSOPerations in my queue, all retrieving unique data.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another idea would be to use blocks. You can initialize your NSOperation object with a block

```
typedef void(^CompletionBlock)(NSData *data);

- (id) initWithCompletionBlock: (CompletionBlock) block;
```

and call it after the operation is finished and data has been downloaded.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(block){
        block(fetchedData);
    }
});
```

Comment: I ended up going this route.  Both answers were right in my mind but this made more sense for my implementation, thank you for the ideas.  I always overlook blocks, have to stop doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the observer pattern to listen for and post notifications that contain necessary data once each operation completes. You would use the [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to handle this. You can find more details in the [Notification Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) section of the documentation. Make sure you take into account which thread you are on no matter which method you use.